# javascript to insert html into a web page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Javascript to insert two li elements into a web page.  The second li gets nested inside the first.

The question is can I create a data structure that have both li elements at the same level. I could adjust me code to do two inserts, but I'm curious if I can do every by a data structure.

Here is my code for inserting the li elements:

```
  // Buid data structure
  // Create first <li> note
  var firstLi = document.createElement("lI");
  var node = document.createTextNode("   ");
  firstLi.appendChild(node);

  // Create second <li> node
  var secondLi = document.createElement("LI");   

  // Append pagination
  // End of with three paginations on page with multipage document
  secondLi.appendChild(clone);                      

  // combine li's
  firstLi.appendChild(secondLi); 

  // Append the cloned <span> element to follow [pulldown]
  document.getElementsByClassName("apple-social-actions-toolbar")[0].appendChild(firstLi);
```

Just above the blue highlighted line you will see the nested li.  I want to have the li at the same level as the enclosing ul.
[image: indented li's]

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, for ul and li to be siblings you need to add them as children to the same parent. Here, you are adding the li as a child of ul (using appendChild)

Answer (score 2):

In your example, your logic for "combining li's" is flawed. It's adding one as a child to the other, not two children at the same level.

```
  // combine li's
  firstLi.appendChild(secondLi); 

  // Append the cloned <span> element to follow [pulldown]
  document.getElementsByClassName("apple-social-actions-toolbar")[0].appendChild(firstLi);
```

should become:

```
  // combine li's
  // remove this: firstLi.appendChild(secondLi); 

  // Append the cloned <span> element to follow [pulldown]
  document.getElementsByClassName("apple-social-actions-toolbar")[0].appendChild(firstLi).appendChild(secondLi);
```

Comment: This effectively does what OP code does. `appendChild` returns the appended element! `.appendChild(firstLi).parentNode.appendChild(secondLi)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
  // Buid data structure
  // Create first <li> note
  var firstLi = document.createElement("lI");
  // \u00A0 is &nbsp;
  var node = document.createTextNode(" \u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0 ");
  firstLi.appendChild(node);

  document.getElementsByClassName("apple-social-actions-toolbar")[0].appendChild(firstLi)

  // Create second <li> node
  var secondLi = document.createElement("LI");   

  // Append pagination
  // End of with three paginations on page with multipage document
  secondLi.appendChild(clone);                      


  // Append the cloned <span> element to follow [pulldown]
  document.getElementsByClassName("apple-social-actions-toolbar")[0].appendChild(secondLi);
```